# Application update, what will be the release date in appstore

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

I recently have released a game for the iOS iPhone devices for which I saw was at the top of the "Release Date" list under the relevant category.

Unfortunately, I had to remove the game from the App Store due to some changes, so I changed the release date to somewhere in the future while I uploaded an update which is waiting for review.

When the update will be approved, Will it be considered released at the same day of the update approval or at the day when the first version was approved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, my update is finally up in the air but unfortunately it is no longer appears as on of the firsts in the release date tabs so Apple probably is using the release date of the first version.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays, apps submitted to the App Store will take 6 to 8 days to be reviewed based on how many apps are queued for review.

If your application is showing the status `Waiting for Review`, it means your app is not yet reviewed by Apple. Once the review process has started, your app will show the status  `Under Review`.

Updates and new releases follow the same rules.

You can also refer [here](http://reviewtimes.shinydevelopment.com/).

Comment: @Melwan I just noticed my question was confusing so your answer is relevant to the first question. (But I did edit my question again to be more clear)