# If my App gets approved, can I set a specific "Release Date"?

Tags: ios-appstore

I'm developing my first App for the App Store, and I'll soon be submitting it. However I need to release it on a specific day for promotional reasons. Since I've never been through the process before, can you tell me if it is possible to set a "release after X" date when submitting the app?

In other words, will my app be automatically "released" as soon as it is approved?

I've found [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/92499/60777) dealing with updates, hoping for an answer specific to a whole new app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the release date through [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/).

The [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/) in the iOS Developer Documentation has a page titled **Managing Your App in iTunes Connect**, where the section [Changing the Availability Date of Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UsingiTunesConnect/UsingiTunesConnect.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH22-SW11) states:

> Use iTunes Connect to set a date when the app is available on the store. For example, you can choose a date that immediately releases the app to the store after it’s approved, or you can set a later date. Using a later availability date allows you to arrange other marketing activities around the launch of your app.
>
> 1. Sign in to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/).
> 2. Select Manage Your Apps.
> 3. Select your app in the Recent Activity section.
> 4. Click Rights and Pricing.
> 5. Choose a date from the Availability Date pop-up menus.
> 6. Optionally, edit the other fields in this form.
> 7. Click Save.
>
> Changes you make to Rights and Pricing go live immediately (expect 24 hours for a full refresh of the changes on the store).

Read the [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/) for more information on managing your app on the App Store.